# HTTP API Design for CRUD App with Many to Many Relationships

Tags: python, ajax, rest, uri, api-design

#### TL;DR

I have a simple CRUD application with lots of Many to Many relationships, and I am responsible for programming the back end, including the database, business logic and the API calls. The only one accessing my APIs is the front end with AJAX calls, and the front end is expected to have an understanding of the data model. I have been calling this REST but after researching this issue have realized that I am not doing "true REST" (and nor do I care to). I only want to create the most effective, intuitive, and beautiful API to accomplish these goals. **What is the best way of designing the URIs, Requests, and Responses for a CRUD app containing Many to Many relationships, used only by the front end?**

#### Requirements

1. The API **must** be able to receive multiple objects in the same HTTP call to optimize.
2. A Foo should be created and associated to Bar (and vice versa) in the same HTTP call, **atomically**. This precludes expecting the front end to create a Foo in one call, and associate it to a Bar in the next.

#### My current design

What follows is the general design I have came up with. These use the example tables `Foo` and `Bar`, with a many to many relationships between them. The junction table is `FooBar`. I.e.,

```
Foo ---< FooBar >--- Bar
```

#### Read all Foos

```
URL: /api/foo
Method: GET
Request: empty
Response: {"data": [{"id": 1, "name": "fizz"}, ...]}
Notes: There isn't a way to read only some specified number
       of foos, as GET doesn't take a Request
```

#### Read one Foo by ID

```
URL: /api/foo/<id>
Method: GET
Request: empty
Response: {"data": {"id": 1, "name": "fizz"}}
```

#### Create a Foo

```
URL: /api/foo/
Method: POST
Request: {"data": [{"name": "fizz"}, ...]}
Response: {"data": [{"id": 1, "name": "fizz"}, ...]}
```

#### Create a Foo and associate it to a Bar

```
URL: /api/foo/
Method: POST
Request: {"data": [{"bar_id": 123, "name": "fizz"}, ...]}
Response: {"data": [{"id": 1, "name": "fizz"}, ...]}
Notes: I know to associate this with a BAR due to the presence
       of a "bar_id" field. I'm not sure if I should also return
       the "foo_bar_id" of the junction table in this response.
```

#### Associate a previously created Foo with a Bar

```
URL: /api/foo/
Method: POST
Request: {"data": [{"id": 1, "bar_id": 123}, ...]}
Response: {"data": {}}
Notes: I know this is a previously created Foo due to the presence
       of a "id", and to associate it to a Bar due to "bar_id".
       I'm not sure if I should return the "foo_bar_id" of the junction
       table in this response.
```

#### Delete the Association between a Foo and a Bar

```
URL: /api/foo
Method: POST
Request: {"data": [{"id": 1, "bar_id": 123}, ...]}
Response: {"data": {}]
Notes: I know to delete the association rather than the Foo due to 
       the presence of the "bar_id". I'm not sure what to return here.
```

#### Delete N Foos

```
URL: /api/foo/
Method: DELETE
Request: {"data": [{"id": 1}, ...]}
Response: {"data": {}}
Notes: Unlike GET, I can specify the number of Foos to delete.
       I'm not sure what to return here.
```

#### Delete one Foo

```
URL: /api/foo/<id>
Method: DELETE
Request: empty
Response: {"data": {}}
Notes: I don't really want to encourage the front end to 
       delete Foos one at a time. I'de rather disable this.
```

#### Update N Foos

```
URL: /api/foo
Method: PUT
Request: {"data": [{"id": 1, ...}, ...]}
Response: {"data": {}}
Notes: I'm not sure what to return here.
```

#### Update 1 Foo

```
URL: /api/foo/<id>
Method: PUT
Request: {"data": {"id": 1, ...}}
Response: {"data": {}}
Notes: I don't really want to encourage the front end to 
       update Foos one at a time. I'de rather disable this. 
       I'm not sure what to return here.
```

Comment: If it's only being used by your front end and you're not interested in being RESTful, just do *whatever you need*. The best way is inevitably either opinion based or too specific to your case to be useful to others.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was assuming that my requirement for a CRUD app with APIs only to be used by the front end was wide spread, that there was a name for it, and some best practices. I was under the impression that this was REST, but after some research learned I was mistaken. Do you know of a name for that which I'm attempting to accomplish?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask?